# Pushing a directory to BitBucket repository using Git

Tags: git

I created a repository on BitBucket and then pushed directory A some time ago. I have made a lot of changes to the directory which are on my local repo. Right now I have pushed the the current directory to the repository in BitBucket using the command below:

```
git push origin master
```

and received the message which reads:

```
remote: Counting objects: 3951, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3443/3443), done.
remote: Total 3951 (delta 404), reused 3945 (delta 402)
Receiving objects: 100% (3951/3951), 7.76 MiB | 46.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (404/404), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

What is surprising is after my work mate has cloned the repository and trying to view the changes,  nothing has changed as in every change that I made is not being shown. it's just as the old directory that was in the server before I pushed the new stuff.

As I push again it's saying "Everything up to date".

Could someone explain what's going on?

Comment: What does `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` say?

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`? Does `origin` in the output match what you'd expect it to?

Comment: try `git branch`. Is there an asterisk besides `master`? Do you see the changes you want on your local files?

Comment: @Makoto , the result for the commant is:    * d93e0a3 (HEAD, origin/master, master) this has been committed
* 89d20f0 Initial commit
* d276f84 (tag: v0.1, tag: v0) hello to Valentinegit status
* 6579ada the first commit

Comment: So looking at that, this tells me that it's on *some* remote branch.  Does your colleague have the same SHA in their local master branch?

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit      origin https://tanatsa@bitbucket.org/therealchiko/caroleslist.git (fetch)
origin https://tanatsa@bitbucket.org/therealchiko/caroleslist.git (push)

Comment: @Harish, Yes there is an asterisk besides the branch master.

Comment: The changes I have made are not being shown. After running any command to show progress it's giving me the commits that where done long before I pushed the current directory

Comment: Here is the thing the thing I'm working on a drupal site. So in my Local repository I can view the site and all the changes I made. But after pushing, if my work mate tries to view the site it's taking him back to installation so that's where I think that no change has taken place

Comment: @Makoto....Yes she does

Comment: Clone the repo again into a new directory. If your changes are there as you'd expect, then it's an issue on the other person's end.